# Q-learning function approximation issue

Tags: reinforcement-learning

I am trying to get the Q value for each state-action using the Q-learning. The idea to approximate the Q is to use some ML algorithm whenever the state space is continuous. The problem that I have is that the actions are extremely correlated with the label, this makes the predictions depend only on the actions and neglect the state.

How can I solve this issue? because whatever I put in the state as explanatory variable, the algorithm still neglect it.  Can I approximate the Q function if my state space is continuous without adopting ML algorithm?

Comment: Sure you can, you can use tile coding for continuous variables, no ML required.

Comment: I'll check this tile coding, thanks a lot.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: @user2974951,  How can I choose the offset? is there any systematic way to do so?

Comment: I don't know, Sutton and Barto in their book mention this and some studies where they tried different parameters and found some which work well. The authors then provide the code to create these tiles, which is in github. See http://www.incompleteideas.net/book/RLbook2018.pdf#page=241 last paragraph starting with "Extensive studies...".